# Where is hard link data stored in the system?

Tags: filesystems, hard-link

I understand that a hard link is a pointer to the inode of a file, but I can't find any information about where the data about the hard link itself is stored; stuff like its name, path and the index of the inode it points to. It can't be in a disk block, because then the disk block would need an inode and another pointer, which is counter-sense. It can't be in the inode itself, because the system needs an pointer to know what inode to look at in the first place. So I don't get it.

Disclaimer: I'm a noob and not a CS student, I'm just trying to learn some Unix. If I'm using wrong terminology, sorry in advance.

Comment: "name, path and the index of the inode it points to" ... that would be the directory entry ("dentry")

Comment: This surely helps. Could you recommend me a resource to learn about this architecture in a more structured way? Maybe a book or a guide.

Comment: A hard link is just another name for a file in the file system. It's stored wherever the filesystem stores names.